# How to define a Lyx Layout for Custom Items?

Tags: lyx, itemize, enumitem, lyx-layouts

I would like to have a list with two alternative bullets. Using the `enumitem`-package, I have already created an `itemize`-environment for one of the two bullets. For the other one, I would use `\item[<code for alternative bullet>]` in Latex, which can be entered easily using Custom Items in Lyx. However, I do not want to enter the command for creating the alternative bullet every time, since items with alternative bullets occur pretty often, so I am wondering whether there is a way to define a Lyx Layout for Custom Items just as we can create Customs Insets for commands.

Ideally, since all items having alternative bullets start with the same Latex command, I would like to wrap both the code for this command and the code for creating the alternative bullet into a single Custom Inset. Does anyone have an idea how this could be done?

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, but consider reading Help > Customization and also take a look at the current layouts used in LyX (inside of lib/layouts folder). The current itemize is just a text file and a normal layout so you can learn from that.